# Nautilus: Automatically mount a bitlocked drived upon login

Tags: nautilus, automount, 23.10

In Nautilus, when I click on "Other locations" then "Encrypted Drive", it gets unlocked and appears as a mounted drive in the list.

**I would like that to be done automatically when I log in** because apps requiring access to that disk can fail if the disk was not mounted first.

Note: In the app "Disks" >> on the corresponding filesystem >> click on the gearwheel >> "edit mount options" >> the option "mount at system startup" is already selected.